# How can I make to PHP write only once selected to the list?

Tags: php, html, html-select, selected, php-8

I'm going to make an HTML list with PHP what is the default value is the current day, month or year.

Like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
while ($start <= $end) {
    if ($start == date("Y") || $start == date("d")  || $start == date("m")) {
        echo "<option selected value='$name'>$start</option> <br>";
    } else {
        echo "<option value='$name'>$start</option> <br>";
    }
    $start++;
}
    
echo "</select>";
```

The problem is the logic is not working fine, because at the day or month can't be separated and it always make 2 selected item in HTML, and, and always applies the last one.

[image: htmllius]

Comment: So you obviously need to make your check look a little closer at whether its being used on a day or a month

Comment: When you're creating the `day` dropdown, you should't compare with `date('m')`, only `date('d')`

Comment: And why are you setting the values all to `Day`? It should be `value='$start'`

Comment: Show all the relevant logic, you have obviously taken a shortcut that you should not have

Comment: Sorry, all of this dropdown maded by one function

Comment: Then you are going to have to rethink that function because its obviously not up to the job

Answer (score 1):

Set a variable to compare with depending on which dropdown you're creating, which is apparently in the `$name` variable. Then you won't mistakely select the Day value that matches the current month, or vice vera.

```
if ($name == 'Year') {
    $selected = date('Y');
} elseif ($name == 'Month') {
    $selected = date('m');
} elseif ($name == 'Day') {
    $selected = date('d');
}

while ($start <= $end) {
    if ($start == $selected) {
        echo "<option selected value='$start'>$start</option> <br>";
    } else {
        echo "<option value='$start'>$start</option> <br>";
    }
    $start++;
}
    
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: You can use `match` instead of `if` to make the code simpler.

Comment: @Dharman It's PHP, so I assume you mean switch/case. I frequently waver over whether to use that when the action is just one line -- having to `break;` after each case makes the code longer.

Comment: No, I meant https://www.php.net/match The question is tagged with PHP 8 so it's safe to use it

Comment: Oh, that's new to me. I don't use PHP 8 yet (regrettably, our infrastructure is a mix of 5.x and 7.2, even 5.4 on one of our critical servers, which causes me no end of pain).

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I recommend at least taking the overview of PHP 8 changes to get familiar with them at a high level. https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php